# lightning component ui:inputdate datepicker

Tags: lightning-aura-components

is there a way to limit the date range that is displayed on the datepicker? Similar to what can be done with query ui datepicker. I'm trying to limit the range to only display a week out.

Comment: do you really need a datepicker then?  If you're only ever needing the next seven days, then perhaps you could just populate a picklist like "Saturday 4/9", "Sunday 4/10", etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring'16, the min and max attribute of ui:inputDate are not supported.
The attributes exist but their access level is not GLOBAL:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputDateComponent/inputDateComponent.intf

Instead of using ui:inputDate, you can use <input type="date" min="yyyy-mm-dd" max="yyyy-mm-dd"> or ui:inputSelect.